# Can't run scheduled celery task

Tags: python, docker, redis, celery, fastapi

I wanted to run some endpoint in Fastapi every 5 minutes using Celery. Also I'm using Docker-compose to run all services I've got.
The problem is when I run:

```
celery -A etl.workers.celery beat --loglevel=INFO
```

I get such an output:

```
celery_worker    | celery beat v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus) is starting.
celery_worker    | __    -    ... __   -        _
celery_worker    | LocalTime -> 2022-09-29 12:56:18
celery_worker    | Configuration ->
celery_worker    |     . broker -> redis://redis:6379/0
celery_worker    |     . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
celery_worker    |     . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
celery_worker    |     . db -> celerybeat-schedule
celery_worker    |     . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
celery_worker    |     . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
celery_worker    | [2022-09-29 12:56:18,220: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
celery_worker    | [2022-09-29 12:56:18,244: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task run_etl_task_every_5_minutes (start_etl)
```

And after that run Flower command:

```
celery -A etl.workers.celery flower --port=5555
```

The output is following:

```
flower           | [I 220929 12:56:19 command:162] Visit me at http://localhost:5555
flower           | [I 220929 12:56:19 command:170] Broker: redis://redis:6379/0
flower           | [I 220929 12:56:19 command:171] Registered tasks:
flower           |     ['ETL pipeline',
flower           |      'celery.accumulate',
flower           |      'celery.backend_cleanup',
flower           |      'celery.chain',
flower           |      'celery.chord',
flower           |      'celery.chord_unlock',
flower           |      'celery.chunks',
flower           |      'celery.group',
flower           |      'celery.map',
flower           |      'celery.starmap']
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:19 command:177] Running without authentication
flower           | [I 220929 12:56:19 mixins:225] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method scheduled failed
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method revoked failed
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method conf failed
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method active_queues failed
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method reserved failed
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method stats failed
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method registered failed
flower           | [W 220929 12:56:20 inspector:42] Inspect method active failed
```

Then in another terminal I execute Celery worker:

```
celery -A etl.workers.celery worker --loglevel=INFO
```

Its output:

```
 -------------- celery@DESKTOP-QODNCDL v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0 2022-09-29 18:56:28
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         workers:0x20a001a1870
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/1
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . ETL pipeline

[2022-09-29 18:56:28,634: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 19232 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:28,662: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 22812 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:28,662: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 20180 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:28,677: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 22844 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:28,677: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 22436 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:28,677: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 21172 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:28,709: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 16532 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:28,709: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 21492 calling self.run()
[2022-09-29 18:56:30,392: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/0: Error 11001 connecting to redis:6379. getaddrinfo failed..
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

.env file:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/1
```

workers.py

```
import time

import requests

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

from etl.env_variables import *

celery = Celery("workers",
                broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL,
                backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)

celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "run_etl_task_every_5_minutes":{
        "task": "start_etl",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/5")
    }
}   

@celery.task(name="ETL pipeline")
def start_etl():
    """
    Starts an ETL process
    and returns its status

    Returns
    -------
    data : dict
        status of the request
    """
    data = {
        "start_datetime": "14-09-2022 12:00:00",
        "type": "up"
    }
    url = "http://localhost:8000/video_operation"

    request = requests.post(url=url,
                            json=data)
    data = request.json()
    return data
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./database:/app/database

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:7.0

  celery_worker:
    container_name: celery_worker
    build: .
    command: sh ./etl/celery_entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - api
      - redis

  flower:
    container_name: flower
    build: .
    command: sh ./etl/flower_entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 5556:5555
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - api
      - redis
      - celery_worker 

  api:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    command: sh api_entrypoint.sh
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - database
```

The code above in workers.py should use Fastapi endpoint and thus inserts a value into postgresql database every 5 minutes. But nothing happen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From your description you are running the celery commands from your local machine and the hostname celery is not defined.,

**You have 2 solutions:**
Both solutions require you tu expose the 6379 port from redis docker so add under redis in docker compose file

```
 ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

1. You define your env on the local machine as:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1
```

2. You edit your /etc/hosts file and add:

```
127.0.0.1 redis
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I found a mistake in the code. I should've used "ETL pipeline" instead of start_etl as a value for "task" key in celery beat schedule configurations.